# Magento Responsive CSS block

Tags: theme, css, rwd

[image: this heather]

i need to make that bar have the same margin as the whole page and be responsive. Im not being able to do so. Im new to css html and stuff, i've tried adding padding, margins, float and was unssucesful, could someone give me a hand?

[Webpage](http://corkandbarrelstore.com/)

Comment: on which screen it's showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on this class `move-block header`

```
element.style {
    margin: 0 14px 0 24px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 1170px;
}
```

and add this

```
.col-xs-12 {
    width: 98%;
}
```